# Choosing an estimator function due to variance and bias

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, bias, mse

I am working on an assignment that requires me to compare two estimators $T1$ & $T2$ for an unknown parameter $\theta$ based on their MSE.

They both have the same MSE of 3, T1 having a variance of 2 and a bias of 1, T2 having a Variance of 2.75 and a Bias of -0.5.

Their MSEs I computed with

\begin{align*}
MSE_1 &= Var_\theta (T_1) + Bias_\theta (T_1)^2 \\
&= 2 + 1^2 = 3
\end{align*}
and

\begin{align*}
MSE_2 &= Var_\theta (T_2) + Bias_\theta (T_2)^2 \\
&= 2.75 + (-0.5)^2 = 3
\end{align*}

So to my knowledge, the estimator with the lower MSE would be the better one.

How do I pick the "more suitable" estimator for said parameter in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way of choosing the better estimator in this case. 
The problem is know as the [Bias-variance tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff).
It depends on your problem and your preferences.

Comment: I assumed something like this, thank you!